# why annotations for some BarMark datapoints have two values in swiftui charts?

Tags: swiftui, charts, weatherkit

I have a chart showing a 10 day forecast using weatherkit, I want to show min and max temp per day so I use a BarMark with two values in the x axis. I want to show annotation for the min and one for the max. but somehow some of them appear double with different values.

[image]
is this an Apple issue or my code issue?

```
struct TenDayForecastViewChart: View {
    let dayWeatherList: [DayWeather]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("10-DAY FORECAST")
                .font(.caption)
                .opacity(0.5)
                .padding()
            
            Chart{
                ForEach(dayWeatherList, id: \.date) { dailyWeather in
                    BarMark(xStart: .value("Temperature", dailyWeather.lowTemperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).value),
                            xEnd: .value("Temperature", dailyWeather.highTemperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).value),
                            y: .value("Day", dailyWeather.date.formatAsAbbreviatedDay())
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                    .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            
                            //Image(systemName: "\(dailyWeather.symbolName)").foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                            Text("\(dailyWeather.lowTemperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).value, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)))")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                    .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .trailing) {
                                                    Text("\(dailyWeather.highTemperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).value, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)))")
                                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                    

                    
                
                }

            }
            //.chartLegend(position: .top, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
            .chartXAxis(.hidden)
            //.chartYAxis(.hidden)
            .frame(height: 250)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose in your 10 days you have 2x "Sun", "Mon", "Tue" each. So the y plot value for these data points is identical, and by default `BarCharts` adds those together.

1. You can pass the full `Date` (not only the day String) into the BarChart and use

```
.value("Day", dailyWeather.date, unit: .day)
```

and add a custom formatting in `.chartYAxis`:

```
.chartYAxis {
    AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day)) { _ in
        AxisGridLine()
        AxisTick()
        AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.weekday(.abbreviated), centered: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked!, you're the best! thanks so much Chris
by the way, the days switched to the right side of the chart, why is that?

Comment: nevermind, I just added a position: .leading to AxisMarks and it worked, thanks again!